# Java - return command

Tags: java, return

i've this function in Java which calls itself multiple times (i.e. is recursive), Based a condition there is a return command as well.

```
public class ReturnTest {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            returnTest(1);
        }

        public static void returnTest(int i){
            System.out.println(" i =>  " + i);
            if(i >= 2) {
                System.out.println(" calling return ");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println(" calling RT1, i =>  " + i);
            returnTest(++i);
            System.out.println(" calling RT2, i =>  "  +i);
            returnTest(++i);
        }
}
```

How does the return command work in this case ?
I was expecting the return command to come out of the initial returnTest() call, however what happens is, it moves onto the next return command

i.e. on return (when i >=2), it calls the following

```
 System.out.println(" calling RT2, i =>  "  +i);
 returnTest(++i);
```

i'm trying to understand how return works (esp in this case), pls. help clarify.

thanks!

Comment: Minor nit - `return` is not a command; it is a keyword which has an explicit and tacit meaning.

Answer (score 4):

I hope the following details will help you :

- you call the method with `1`
- `>=2` is **false** so continue
- you call the method with `2` (because of pre-incrementation)

  - `>=2` is **true** so it **returns** to the upper level
- you call the method with `3` (because of pre-incrementation)

  - `>=2` is **true** so it **returns**  to the upper level
- no more code, end of execution